# How to store long public key string in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am testing out some PGP encryption in Flutter using the [openpgp](https://pub.dev/packages/openpgp) package. I'm trying to encrypt using a public key, but I'm not sure how to store such a long string.

Here is their example:

```
var result = await OpenPGP.encrypt("text","[publicKey here]");
```

Here is a example public key, but I can't store it properly. Even using `r"key"` I get many errors.
[image: public PGP key]

Comment: Try using a [multi-line, raw string literal](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings) (`r""" ... """`).

Comment: @jamesdlin good to know, thanks. Didn’t know that was a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in a example document for simple_rsa this is how they store the key:

```
  final PUBLIC_KEY =
      "MIIBITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ4AMIIBCQKCAQBuAGGBgg9nuf6D2c5AIHc8" +
          "vZ6KoVwd0imeFVYbpMdgv4yYi5obtB/VYqLryLsucZLFeko+q1fi871ZzGjFtYXY" +
          "9Hh1Q5e10E5hwN1Tx6nIlIztrh5S9uV4uzAR47k2nng7hh6vuZ33kak2hY940RSL" +
          "H5l9E5cKoUXuQNtrIKTS4kPZ5IOUSxZ5xfWBXWoldhe+Nk7VIxxL97Tk0BjM0fJ3" +
          "8rBwv3++eAZxwZoLNmHx9wF92XKG+26I+gVGKKagyToU/xEjIqlpuZ90zesYdjV+" +
          "u0iQjowgbzt3ASOnvJSpJu/oJ6XrWR3egPoTSx+HyX1dKv9+q7uLl6pXqGVVNs+/" +
          "AgMBAAE=";
```